# 分かっています and 知っています - Do they all mean "I know"?

Tags: grammar, meaning, verbs

As the title denotes, I have lots of vaguenesses in making it clear between 分かっています and 知っています - Is their meaning all "I know"?

Hence, I can't stop thinking about these two:

- 中国語を知っていますか?
- 中国語が分かっていますか?

Do they have the same meaning? Can we use them interchangeably?

Answer (score 3):

> •中国語を知っていますか?
>   はい、もちろん知っています。中国で話されている言葉ですよね。
>   Yes, off course, I know it. It's the language spoken in Chaina.
>   •中国語が分かっていますか? （中国語が分かりますか？）
>   いいえ、分かりません。
>   No, I don't understand it. I can't read and hear it. (I can't read, hear, speak and write it.)

> •ドナルド・トランプを知っていますか?
>   はい、もちろん知っています。アメリカの大統領ですよね。
>   Yes, off course, I know him. He is the president of US. (I know him through TV news everyday.)
>   •ドナルド・トランプが（どんな人物か、何を考えているのか）分かっていますか?
>   いいえ、分かりません。世界中の人が、まだ分かっていないと思います。
>   No, I don't understand him. He is very hard to understand for everybody in the world.

Answer (score 1):

知っています literally means you KNOW ABOUT sth
分かっています literally means you UNDERSTAND sth

Comment: I think that is oversimplifying it. Associating two English translations to two Japanese words that are interchangeable in many contexts may actually not be very helpful.

Comment: I feel like this is the most direct way to help OP to understand the difference between those two. I understand that those two words are interchangeable under many situation. However, this is the  fundamental difference. I don't care that much about downvotes but this answer does not deserve one.

Comment: Sorry, I only left a comment and didn't downvote you. I don't think it's a bad approach to an answer, but it would probably be a better answer if you expanded on this analogy (for example, give sentences where these two have the desired connotations and also give examples where this analogy breaks down).

Comment: ＠BeyondRiver - Re: the posters specific question about 中国語,  do your definitions fit the meanings of his sentences?  I feel it does, but I'm not certain it is absolute.  

To make life difficult, 「分かっている　和かっている　判っている　解っている」can all use the pronunciation 「わかっている」 , yet they clearly can have different nuances: understand, know about, judge, solve.

Comment: ^ 「和かっている」って・・・？